# fftshift on a 3D matrix on GPU

Tags: matlab, gpu, fft

I have an 3D matrix `512*512*100`. I want to apply `fftshift` on each page of it using the GPU. What I am doing right now is:

```
  G = rand(512,512,100, 'gpuArray');
  for i=1:100
      G(:,:,i) = fftshift(G(:,:,i));
  end
```

Is there a faster way to apply `fftshift` without doing it in a loop? For example, `fft2` can be applied directly to an 3D array performing the operation on each page separately. However, `fftshift` does not work like that. Furthermore, `fftshift` is not supported by `pageFun`.

Comment: What about `fftshift(G,3)`? `fftn` can perform N-D transforms, and `fft` can operate along any arbitrary dimension, but `fftshift` seems to only be able to swap within a dimension, or 2 at a time (what you're doing here). `circshift` could come in handy as well, although I'm not sure whether that has the desired speed-up.

Comment: Maybe `fftshift(fftshift(G,1),2)`?

Comment: @Adriaan Thanks. fftshift(G,3) does not seems to produce the same output of my code.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It did the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fftshift` has an optional second input argument that selects along which dimension to apply the shift. Unfortunately, it is not possible to provide two dimensions, so `fftshift(G,[1,2])` will not work. You'll have to call `fftshift` twice:

```
G = fftshift(fftshift(G,1),2);
```

Hopefully this is faster than calling it 100 times for a single page.

Comment: Your way turns out faster on my GTX 1060 GPU. Thanks!